# Help with Convergence/Divergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

So I am trying to prove whether the following problem converges or diverges?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left({n\over n+18}\right)^n$$

So I decided to use the Root test.

$$ L = \lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left({n\over n+18}\right)^n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} {n\over n+18} = 1$$

But that answer is inconclusive, because according to the Root Test, if L $\lt 1$ than the function converges, and if L $\gt 1$, than the function diverges. But my answer is 1. Can someone please suggest some other methods through which I can determine whether the given problem converges or diverges? Thanks Alot

Comment: I always tell my students that the first thing they should consider is:"Does the nth term go to 0?" If not, the series cannot converge. Sanath and Andre are giving you great advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the limit test:

> If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{n}{n+18}\right)^n$ is not $0$ or does not exist, $\sum \left(\dfrac{n}{n+18}\right)^n$ diverges. Else the test is inconclusive.

Indeed, $\sum \left(\dfrac{n}{n+18}\right)^n$ diverges.

Comment: Dear @Sanath you mean if it's *not* zero or ..., right?

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\left(\frac{n+18}{n}\right)^n=\left(1+\frac{18}{n}\right)^n$. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n=e^x$, we conclude that 
$\left(\frac{n+18}{n}\right)^n$
 has limit $e^{18}$. So the terms of our series have limit $e^{-18}$, and in particular do not approach $0$. It follows that the series diverges.